# Sentence patterns for starting a picture description

Tags: syntax

I'm trying to do some picture descriptions to practice my Japanese (which is quite at a beginner level), just to avoid to focus only on grammar and 漢字 memorization, which can become really boring sometimes.

So my question is, how could I express something like `This picture is about xxx` or `In this picture, (you can see/there is) xxx` in Japanese?

My attempt at this is

> このしゃしんの中に、ｘｘｘいます。
>
> (xxx = the main object in the photo)

Any comment or suggestion about this?

I was looking for easy sentence patterns. I don't aim at building complex discourses, I'm just trying to keep the level slightly higher with respect to what I can achieve without consulting a dictionary or grammar.

Comment: Would you actually say "This picture is about xxx" or "In this picture, (you can see/there is) xxx" in English?"

Comment: Actually my original question did not have those examples, but was more vague. I was more thinking about "this photo shows xxx" or "in this photo, you can see xxx". I don't know if these are correct either but they seem more natural to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This picture is about xxx.

You would say 「この[写真]{しゃしん}はxxxです。」 Alternatively you could say it 「これは、xxxの[写真]{しゃしん}です。」 (Literally 'This is a photo of xxx').

> In this picture, (you can see/there is) xxx.

「この写真には、xxxが[写]{うつ}っています。」

Comment: So you mean there is no natural way to tell what's in a photo other than saying "this is a photo of a/an xxx"?

Comment: @mandrake Edited. 「この写真はxxxです」 and 「この写真には、xxxが写っています。」 are the most natural ways that I can think of to directly say "This picture is about xxx" and "In this picture, (you can see/there is) xxx" respectively.